# How to create a list or vector of data frames that can be updated individually?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I need a way to access a group of data frames either by index (e.g., a list or a vector of data frames) so I can add vector results to one of the group of data frames using rbind() without having to explicitly specify the data frame by name. In other words, I will be computing the name or index of the data frame I will be updating in the R code. For example, I might have:

```
x1 <- data.frame(A = c(3,4), B = c( 5, 6))
x2 <- data.frame(A = c(7, 8), B = c(9, 10))
p <- c(12, 13)
```

and I want to be able to add `p` to, say, `x2`, using `rbind(x2, p)` but I either need to have the names of the data frames in some kind of indexed variable so I can compute the data frame that will be updated, or perhaps a list of data frames. What is the best way to handle this? Help always much appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what you need.  If you need to create a list of data.frames based on the object names, `lst <- mget(ls(pattern='x\\d+'))` then `rbind(lst[[1]], p)`

Comment: Not sure I totally understand the code snippet above, but I think that code retrieves an index on the series of names, “xn” where n is 1, 2, ... If so, that’s not my question. My question is more general. I just used x1, x2 as an example of some names of the example data frames. I think the question whose answer I seek is how to create a list of data frames and then be able to retrieve a single data frame from the list for updating by using a computed index (number) or computed data frame name. There may also be a way of doing a vector of data frames but I don’t think that is allowed in R.

Comment: My code gives a `list` based on the `object names` of the data.frames created in the global envronment.  If you need to create a list of data.frames, just do `lst <- list(x1, x2)`  I don't get the `vector of dataframes`, but if you meant , `v1 <- c('x1', 'x2')` then `mget(v1)` is the same as the one I showed earlier with `mget(ls(...`

Comment: OK. Sorry. I haven’t used mget before. You reply gives me the answer which I will post below. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Also, if you need to `rbind` both `list` elements, `Map(rbind, mget(ls(pattern='x\\d+)), p)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer formulated from akrun’s comments.

```
x <- matrix(A = (c(3,4), B = c( 5, 6))
y <- data.frame(A = c(7, 8), B = c(9, 10))
# and so on ... many other data frames
z <- list(x,y)  # all bound into a list
p <- c(12, 13)
# then the elements of the list can be accessed by index and converted
# back to a data frame for rbind
rbind(as.data.frame(z[[2]]), p)
```